# Monitor won't stay off

Tags: power-management, graphics, monitors, intel-graphics, gdm3

I have a computer that runs both as a server, and also as a workstation, and this means that it should not sleep, but also have a graphical desktop enabled.

To achieve this, I set the following values in `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`

```bash
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=5
# - What to do after sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
#   'blank', 'suspend', 'shutdown', 'hibernate', 'interactive' or 'nothing'
sleep-inactive-ac-type='blank'
```

I have also added inhibitors `shutdown:sleep:idle:handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch` with systemd.

This seems to almost work, but the problem is that the screen of the computer stays on, and doesn't go to power save mode. After power save activates, in immediately turns on again. See video below:

[image]

https://i.imgur.com/LvuI26V.gifv

To debug the situation, also disabled wayland from `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`, and then ran

```bash
sleep 3; xset dpms force off
```

with the same behavior.

How can I correct the problem of the monitor not staying off?

The display driver is

```bash
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation AlderLake-S GT1 (rev 0c)
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. AlderLake-S GT1
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

For the `i915` kernel driver I have:

```
$ sudo modinfo -p i915
modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=disable, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int)
enable_dc:Enable power-saving display C-states. (-1=auto [default]; 0=disable; 1=up to DC5; 2=up to DC6; 3=up to DC5 with DC3CO; 4=up to DC6 with DC3CO) (int)
enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default: -1 (use per-chip default)) (int)
lvds_channel_mode:Specify LVDS channel mode (0=probe BIOS [default], 1=single-channel, 2=dual-channel) (int)
panel_use_ssc:Use Spread Spectrum Clock with panels [LVDS/eDP] (default: auto from VBT) (int)
vbt_sdvo_panel_type:Override/Ignore selection of SDVO panel mode in the VBT (-2=ignore, -1=auto [default], index in VBT BIOS table) (int)
reset:Attempt GPU resets (0=disabled, 1=full gpu reset, 2=engine reset [default]) (uint)
vbt_firmware:Load VBT from specified file under /lib/firmware (charp)
error_capture:Record the GPU state following a hang. This information in /sys/class/drm/card<N>/error is vital for triaging and debugging hangs. (bool)
enable_hangcheck:Periodically check GPU activity for detecting hangs. WARNING: Disabling this can cause system wide hangs. (default: true) (bool)
enable_psr:Enable PSR (0=disabled, 1=enable up to PSR1, 2=enable up to PSR2) Default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)
psr_safest_params:Replace PSR VBT parameters by the safest and not optimal ones. This is helpful to detect if PSR issues are related to bad values set in  VBT. (0=use VBT parameters, 1=use safest parameters) (bool)
enable_psr2_sel_fetch:Enable PSR2 selective fetch (0=disabled, 1=enabled) Default: 0 (bool)
force_probe:Force probe options for specified supported devices. See CONFIG_DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE for details. (charp)
disable_power_well:Disable display power wells when possible (-1=auto [default], 0=power wells always on, 1=power wells disabled when possible) (int)
enable_ips:Enable IPS (default: true) (int)
fastboot:Try to skip unnecessary mode sets at boot time (0=disabled, 1=enabled) Default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)
load_detect_test:Force-enable the VGA load detect code for testing (default:false). For developers only. (bool)
force_reset_modeset_test:Force a modeset during gpu reset for testing (default:false). For developers only. (bool)
invert_brightness:Invert backlight brightness (-1 force normal, 0 machine defaults, 1 force inversion), please report PCI device ID, subsystem vendor and subsystem device ID to dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, if your machine needs it. It will then be included in an upcoming module version. (int)
disable_display:Disable display (default: false) (bool)
memtest:Perform a read/write test of all device memory on module load (default: off) (bool)
mmio_debug:Enable the MMIO debug code for the first N failures (default: off). This may negatively affect performance. (int)
verbose_state_checks:Enable verbose logs (ie. WARN_ON()) in case of unexpected hw state conditions. (bool)
nuclear_pageflip:Force enable atomic functionality on platforms that don't have full support yet. (bool)
edp_vswing:Ignore/Override vswing pre-emph table selection from VBT (0=use value from vbt [default], 1=low power swing(200mV),2=default swing(400mV)) (int)
enable_guc:Enable GuC load for GuC submission and/or HuC load. Required functionality can be selected using bitmask values. (-1=auto [default], 0=disable, 1=GuC submission, 2=HuC load) (int)
guc_log_level:GuC firmware logging level. Requires GuC to be loaded. (-1=auto [default], 0=disable, 1..4=enable with verbosity min..max) (int)
guc_firmware_path:GuC firmware path to use instead of the default one (charp)
huc_firmware_path:HuC firmware path to use instead of the default one (charp)
dmc_firmware_path:DMC firmware path to use instead of the default one (charp)
enable_dp_mst:Enable multi-stream transport (MST) for new DisplayPort sinks. (default: true) (bool)
enable_dpcd_backlight:Enable support for DPCD backlight control(-1=use per-VBT LFP backlight type setting [default], 0=disabled, 1=enable, 2=force VESA interface, 3=force Intel interface) (int)
enable_gvt:Enable support for Intel GVT-g graphics virtualization host support(default:false) (bool)
request_timeout_ms:Default request/fence/batch buffer expiration timeout. (uint)
lmem_size:Set the lmem size(in MiB) for each region. (default: 0, all memory) (uint)
lmem_bar_size:Set the lmem bar size(in MiB). (uint)
mitigations:Selectively enable security mitigations for all Intel® GPUs in the system.

  auto -- enables all mitigations required for the platform [default]
  off  -- disables all mitigations

Individual mitigations can be enabled by passing a comma-separated string,
e.g. mitigations=residuals to enable only clearing residuals or
mitigations=auto,noresiduals to disable only the clear residual mitigation.
Either '!' or 'no' may be used to switch from enabling the mitigation to
disabling it.

Active mitigations for Ivybridge, Baytrail, Haswell:
  residuals -- clear all thread-local registers between contexts
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the solution to the problem was with the monitor itself, and had nothing to do with the OS or the drivers:

As the monitor has two-HDMI inputs ports, when it went into power-save mode, it triggered a scan, and then it turned on again.

When I manually selected only the HDMI-1 port, and disabled automatic scanning, the monitor started to enter power-save mode as it should.

Not sure if this is a bug in the specific monitor or somewhere else in the stack, but this solution seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to adjust the settings on the monitor itself eg push the buttons on the monitor until i came to the "select output" and change it from "auto" to "HDMI 1" save and exit. Solved my issues with wayland not turning off the monitor, as the monitor went into autoscan mode, which triggered a wakeup.